# OpenXML generate Report from Excel Model

Tags: vb.net

I need your help to understand how to populate a new excel by copying it from a template using Openxml.
I would like to keep the formatting of the columns deriving from the template;

```vb
     Public Sub ExportDTfromModel(ByVal pathmodel As String, ByVal pathdestination As String, ByVal dt As System.Data.DataTable)
            u.SegnalaSoloLog("Inizio Metodo: " & MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString())
            Try
                If System.IO.File.Exists(pathmodel) Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(pathmodel, pathdestination)


                    Using spreadSheet As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(pathdestination, True)
                        Dim WorksheetPart As WorksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, dt.TableName)
                        If (Not WorksheetPart Is Nothing) Then
                            Dim worksheet As Worksheet = New Worksheet()
                            WorksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet
                            Dim sheetData As SheetData = New SheetData()


                            Dim headerRow As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()
                            Dim columns As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

                            For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                                columns.Add(column.ColumnName)
                                Dim cell As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
                                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
                                cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName)
                                '    Dim headerCell As Cell = createTextCell(
                                'ds.Columns.IndexOf(column) + 1,
                                '1,
                                'column.ColumnName)

                                headerRow.AppendChild(cell)
                            Next

                            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow)

                            'For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Rows.Count - 1
                            '    Dim contentRow As DataRow
                            '    contentRow = ds.Rows(i)
                            '    sheetData.AppendChild(createContentRow(contentRow, i + 2))
                            'Next


                            For Each dsrow As DataRow In dt.Rows
                                Dim newRow As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()

                                For Each col As String In columns
                                    Dim cell As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
                                    ' cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String


                                    Select Case dsrow(col).GetType().ToString
                                        Case "System.DateTime"
                                            cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(Convert.ToDateTime(dsrow(col)))
                                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Date
                                        Case "System.Decimal"
                                            cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(Convert.ToDecimal(dsrow(col)))
                                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number
                                        Case "System.String"
                                            cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow(col).ToString)
                                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String

                                    End Select



                                    newRow.AppendChild(cell)
                                Next

                                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow)
                            Next
                        End If
                        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()

                        GC.Collect()
                        u.SegnalaSoloLog("File Excel Generato in : " & pathdestination)

                    End Using

                Else
                    u.SegnalaSoloLog("Errore Modello non trovato, impossibile esportare il file")
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                u.SegnalaSoloLog("Errore in Export from model: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: You are not telling us what is the actual problem you are facing. Please explain in detail what the code does and what is it that you want it to do instead.

Comment: currently the attached code writes the value in the cells not considering the formatting from which I copied the sheet